# python requests strips form data when content type is multipart/form-data?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to replicate the cURL command below with Python requests, but it seems like requests is **stripping** the Form data and not adding the right content length and boundary information as I expected. Here are the details:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer xyzabc1234" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "firstArgument=http://www.somewebsite.com/Images/pic.jpg" -F "secondArgument=YaddaYadda" http://httpbin.org/post
```

I'm trying to issue the request as:

```
r = requests.post(url='http://httpbin.org/post', 
headers={
    'Authorization':'Bearer XYZ1233', 
    'Cache-Control':'no-cache', 
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}, 
data={
    'firstArg':'https://www.fakesiteyolo.com/Images/ok.jpg', 
    'secondArg':'YaddaYadda'})
```

When using cURL I get a response like:

```
{
    "args": {},
    "data": "",
    "files": {},
    "form": {
    "firstArg": "YaddaYadda",
    "secondArg": "https://www.fakesiteyolo.com/Images/ok.jpg"
},
    "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Authorization": "Bearer ABC12345",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "320",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------2a19bf0d22dbe8a3",
    "Expect": "100-continue",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.47.1"
    },
    "json": null,
    "origin": "203.63.117.8",
    "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

We can clearly see the form data in there, however when I use requests I get this:

```
    {
    'args': {},
    'data': '',
    'files': {},
    'form': {},
    'headers': {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer XYZ1233',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Content-Length': '75',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Host': 'httpbin.org',
        'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.2'
    },
    'json': None,
    'origin': '203.63.117.8',
    'url': 'http://httpbin.org/post'
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry Coldspeed, I thought I did provide the code, is there something missing? The cURL and requests.post are there?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the requests code.

Comment: Try adding another header to your requests code: `"User-Agent": "curl/7.47.1"`

Comment: why are you adding `multipart` in your headers if you're not posting any files?

Answer (score 0):

So this is somewhat a limitation of Python Requests, and I can achieve what I wanted to achieve via requests_toolbelt by following:

http://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html#streaming-multipart-data-encoder